# Iterate a FormArray of FormGroups

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I'm having trouble getting my form array of form groups to work.

I'd like to iterate over the form array and render the inputs in each form group. When I call `addExercise()` the template doesn't render the new form group that I push to the form array. Also when I call `saveWorkout()` the `console.log(this.workoutFormArray.value)` line shows that the values from my inputs are not reflected.

**workout.component.ts**

```
workoutFormArray: FormArray;

ngOnInit() {
  this.workoutFormArray = new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      exercise: new FormControl(''),
      reps: new FormControl('')
    })
  ]);
}

addExercise() {
  this.workoutFormArray.push(
    new FormGroup({
      exercise: new FormControl(''),
      reps: new FormControl(''),
    })
  );
}

saveWorkout() {
  console.log(this.workoutFormArray.value);
}
```

**workout.component.html**

```
<ion-icon (click)="addExercise()" name="add" slot="end"></ion-icon>

<div [formArrayName]="workoutFormArray">
  <div *ngFor="let group of workoutFormArray.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <ion-select 
        placeholder="Exercise"
        formControlName="group.controls.exercise"
        (ionChange)="saveWorkout()"
      >
        <ion-select-option [value]="pushups"> Pushups </ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option [value]="squats"> Squats </ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>

      <ion-input 
        type="text"
        formControlName="group.controls.reps"
      ></ion-input>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="saveWorkout()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would like to ask, does your `formArray` is the root of form? Or there is a `FormGroup` that wrap the `FormArray`? Thanks.

Comment: The formArray is the root

Comment: Noted, done update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**: You mentioned that the `workoutFormArray` `FormArray` is the root of the form, you may have a read on this reported issue in GitHub: [Supporting [formArray] without a [formGroup] parent #30264](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30264).

```
<div [formGroup]="$any(workoutFormArray)">
  ...
</div>
```

The problem was that you provided the wrong `formControlName` to the nested `FormGroup`. It should be:

```
<ion-select
  placeholder="Exercise"
  formControlName="exercise"
  (ionChange)="saveWorkout()"
>
  <ion-select-option value="pushups"> Pushups </ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="squats"> Squats </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

<ion-input type="text" formControlName="reps"></ion-input>
```

Without the prefix `group.controls.`.

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msxvbc?file=src/app/workout/workout.component.html)